# How to intercept file update in Linux?

Tags: linux, io, filesystems

I have a directory /home/my_username/my_directory

For every file inside my_directory, I want if the file is updated, then the diff between the old version and the new version would be generated, and then a specific program (my own program) will be notified about it.

Comment: You use the 'inotify' mechanism in Linux to do that - however if you need more help, you should specify your programming language. However, people arn't going to write the entire program for you.

Comment: @nos : I thought inotify would only notify me once the update is performed (thus I can't do the diff), no?

Comment: Yes, so you better code the application to make a backup of the original file when it is changed. (Or just keep those files in a version control system)

Comment: @nos : that's possible, git does that, except that the "hidden" files are only updated during commits, but then i will need twice the size of the storage. how does dropbox do it, then? i'm quite sure that they also "listen" to file system events, but they need to do diff when the file is updated. does dropbox keep the "old copy" as well?

Comment: Dropbox does not provide low level read/writre access to filesystem and dropbox app logic may do diff before overwriting data at the underlying filesystem. Note that dropbox provides complete revision history and not only diff with last version.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "File system in user space" (FUSE) available under http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse/

It allows you to intercept and modify every file system access for a given directory (you have to mount it first with your own FUSE driver).

You find a tutorial of how to do this under http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/fuse-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks. I have known this alternative (although I haven't tried it), though. I wish there is a simpler alternative, but I do keep Fuse as the option of the last resort.